# Pros and cons of using a MIDI file to improve rhythm during practice

Tags: practice, rhythm, midi, metronomes

I'm an adult beginner piano and harp player and the thing I struggle the most with is rhythm.

I have the most difficulty in songs in which the beat is a quarter note and there are eight or dotted quarter notes. In those cases the only way I can get it close to correct is to convert for example a 4/4 to 8/8 and count like that.

One thing that helps me improve my timing is to generate a MIDI file with the score and try to follow that as a play. But my former teacher strongly advised me not to do that. He said I sounded robotic and that I wouldn't improve my sense of tempo if I did that.

IMO I sound robotic anyway therefore if I could sound robotic while playing the song correctly that would be preferable to being robotic and incorrect. :) I think it's easier for me to first learn the notes, then the rhythm, and then try to add some expression on top of that. But I wouldn't want this strategy to become something preventing me to develop my own tempo.

My new teacher recommends me to use a metronome, but that is much more difficult in particular for cases when there are subdivisions of the beat.

So I'd like to hear more opinions regarding the use of a MIDI file as a tool to help practice.

Answer (score 1):

I  haven't noticed a difference in MIDI vs Metronome. Try clapping (or using claves or rhythm sticks) to beat out various rhythms. You need to develop a good sense of rhythm to be able to add expression. You can learn both at once.

It does take quite a bit of repetition to get rhythm patterns into muscle memory.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it's easier for me to first learn the notes, then the rhythm...

I've seen people struggle when they seem to be doing that - it should be possible to think about them together (e.g. as a whole melody) so that you're thinking about one thing rather than two. Possibly you want to have the piece as a whole (the right notes, with the right rhythm) in your "mind's ear" before you play.

> One thing that helps me improve my timing is to generate a MIDI file
>   with the score and try to follow that as a play.

There's nothing particularly wrong with playing along with a recording, and playing along with a MIDI file would be similar,  but if it becomes the only way you practice, it might stop you developing that "mind's ear" ability. I'd recommend using a mixture of tactics:

- Trying to play cold from the sheet music (so that the written notes are your only guide)
- generating a midi file, listening to it a few times, and then try to play the piece (both with and without the score in front of you).
- perhaps later on, play along with the full MIDI version to check your interpretation. (You might want to double check with someone that your MIDI file is right, as well!)

> In those cases the only way I can get it close to correct is to
>   convert for example a 4/4 to 8/8 and count like that.

I think I know what you mean, but you don't have to think of it as converting to 8/8 - it's just a question of hearing the subdivisions between the four beats. Sometimes people count 1 - *and* - 2 - *and* - 3 - *and* - 4 - *and* -, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem with READING the rhythms or with getting your fingers to play them?

If I was teaching you I might approach this by getting you to sing the melodic line - reading the notation would be good, imitating ME singing it would be fine.  Then tap out the rhythm on the table-top.  Finally try to play it.  If it fumbles, was your hand in a position so it COULD play it?  Or maybe you have to start the routine over, but S..L..O..W..E..R.

I see little point in practicing the piece with the wrong rhythms.